# how to play video in vlc from java

Tags: java, oracle, video, vlc

I'm working on a school project and I have to save a video in oracle database as ORDVIDEO and play it back after that.
I'm using java and already chose a video played it on vlc using

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe", videopath);
            Process start = pb.start();
```

and I successfully inserted the video in the database as ordvideo, and retrieved it again.

Now all I need is to find a way to play it again since now I don't have a path but the video itself.

Do you have an idea on how I can do that ?

Comment: There's also a Java interface for VLC, which allows you to play videos inside your own Java application using VLC - see [VLCJ](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/)